# Enterprise Library Logging and click once applications

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce, enterprise-library

We have a WPF application that logs exceptions (currently to a file) using Enterprise Library.

We are now planning to distribute this application using click once. If I have understood it correctly a click once application has limited access to the local harddisk.

So question is which location can Entlib write log entries to? Is there any special configuration required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce Apps support the concepts of Isolated Storage and Data Directory. See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753568/where-can-i-write-my-log4net-log-file-to-under-clickonce) and the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx). The log4net example in the SO post should guide you into the right direction.