# Why not logging is done after converting to click once app or exe?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have created a console app in which logging is done correctly using log4net. But after publishing my app (Click once app or .exe) logging is not working, even though my application is working fine.

Is there any way to make log4net work in my final click-once app?

Comment: @Martin James: please see my edited question.

Comment: Check if all necessary prerequisites are included in your ClickOnce installation. And where should it be logging to?

Comment: how can i check necesary pre req?? I have included all the dlls and the log4net.config is present there inside my console app..

Comment: Get hold of the log4net source code and debug through it to find out why it is not logging.

Comment: But its working when it is debugging..when i publish my app(console or windows form)as click once app,its not logging..

Comment: @Vysakh - you have the source code, the app, the debugger, the test environment, config files, support DLLs etc.  We have three sentences in a blog.  What do you wish us to do?  Also, Maarten asked 'where should it be logging to?'.

Comment: sorry for the vague comment...Actually I have my supporting DLL's, config files and other programming stuffs in my console app.When I debug my project, log is correctly created and gets updated.But whenever I publish my program as click once app or exe the program runs smoothly,but log doesnt get created.I want log4net to create log file and update it in a location(eg:D:\Logs\)>it does its job nicely in debug mode..but not working after publishing.

I want all of you to support me in this regard on how I can achieve log creation after publishing my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself..

The only thing we need to do is change the build action of Log4net from "NONE" to "Content".Then publish your application and you can find the log being cretaed while the app is running.

Thanks everyone for your response..

Comment: Do you mean the build action of Log4net.config (xml file)? I did that but still not working

Comment: glautrou, you should set copy to output directory as "copy always" for your log4net.config file. Do a build, it should work as expected..

Answer (score 0):

You need specific permissions (FileIOPermission) to access files outside of isolated storage. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx